# Celery 4.2-Django RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: django, celery, supervisord

My `__init__.py` file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

My `celery.py` file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
app = Celery('myproject')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

my **`/etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf`** file:

```
[program:]
command=/home/user/venv/bin/celery -A myproject worker --loglevel=INFO
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/user/project-folder
user=user
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/home/user/logs/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/user/logs/celery.log
startssecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
stopasgroup=true
priority=100
```

and this is the last section of the error message in `celery.log`

```
File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 131, in config_from_object
   self._conf = force_mapping(obj)
File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 48, in force_mapping
   return DictAttribute(m) if not isinstance(m, Mapping) else m
File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/abc.py", line 183, in __instancecheck__
   subclass = instance.__class__
File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site- packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 215, in inner
   self._setup()
File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
   self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
   mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 894, in _find_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1157, in find_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1129, in _get_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1273, in find_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1231, in _get_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 556, in 
spec_from_file_location
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I don't know whats wrong with this configuration?

Comment: how do you run these commands?

Comment: I am using `supervisor` to start the `gunicorn` and `celery` in two separate `conf` files. Gunicorn runs well but my celery workers don't. The command to start the celery workers is the first line in my `celery.conf` file

Comment: Can you make sure your priority is different on gunicorn? I think gunicorn should be first, then celery

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge and @wdfc that's actually what is happening. I also have my `gunicorn.conf` file. When  I run `sudo supervisorctl reread` and then `sudo supervisorctl update` the gunicorn daemon is run first, and then it fails with celery.conf, with the above message

Comment: too late for you, but maybe helpful for someone else. Make sure the environment variables set in your gunicorn.service are also set in the celery.service and clean up any old files in __pycache__ after hours of trying things.

Answer (score 7):

I also have the same problem, when I delete the following sentence

```
 app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

then it works. So I think the problem is happend because of that.
Maybe we should specify the config of this function.

Comment: oh , I'm sorry to say that the sentence is app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY'), not app.auto...

Comment: Somehow that works, but don't know why? Perhaps, the official document says to have that line.

Answer (score 4):

```
from django.conf import settings

app.config_from_object(settings, namespace='CELERY')
```

Actually this `settings` go in there.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be importing your celery app in your `__init__.py` file.  Take that out and it will fix your infinite startup import loop.  Essentially, your celery app kicks off the django settings module initialization which in turn loads the apps and tries to reload the project `__init__.py` file which loads your celery file, which then tries to reload the settings file because it hasn't initialized which in turn . . . (you get the idea).

Comment: I keep having the same error. I had no choice, I've spent 2 weeks banging my head to the desk and I had to do a workaround:    `def threader(task,*args):
    t = threading.Thread(target=task, args=args)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()`. With this patch I call the method and its parameters and that does my email stuff. I put this function inside a utils.py file I have in my project

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone - I had a similar problem and it was caused by an exception in the overridden `on_configure` method of `Celery` class. I guess anything that prevents `Celery._load_config` method from executing normally might cause the "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error.

Answer (score 0):

I try to comment the line

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

and the error is gone. When the celery-related settings are not found in settings.py, it gives me this error. After that, I add

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379'

It works again. I'm using docker compose to set up django + redis + celery. I guess it cannot detect the settings.py file without any celery settings